# Split Regex digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a street address : 
21 rue Poliveau, 75005 Paris

My output needs to be like :

```
[21]
[rue Poliveau]
[,]
[75005]
[Paris]
```

This is for HTML script (Website Angular)

```
var regex = /\s?([(\d+),(\b)])\s?/;
var resultat = query.split(regex);
for(var i=0; i<resultat.length;i++)
{console.log(resultat[i]);
```

Despite \d+ my output is :

```
[2]
[1]
[rue Poliveau]
[,]
[7]
[5]
[0]
[0]
[5]
[Paris]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using match would be easier than split using following regex,

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?: *[a-zA-Z]+)*|\d+|[^\w\s]
```

**Explanation for above regex:**

- `[a-zA-Z]+(?: *[a-zA-Z]+)*` - Match space separated alphabets
- `|` - Alternation
- `\d+` - Match one or more digits
- `|` - Alternation
- `[^\w\s]` - Match one or more non-word non-space characters

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJvxyn/1)**

Try these JS codes,

```js
var s = '21 rue Poliveau, 75005 Paris'
console.log(s.match(/[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+(?: *[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+)*|\d+|[^\w\s]/g))
s = "25 chemin de l'école, Saint-Rémy-de-Provence"
console.log(s.match(/[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+(?: *[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+)*|\d+|[^\w\s]/g))
```

**Edit:**

For supporting accentuated characters, I am enhancing the regex to this, where `À-ÿ` range should cover the needed characters as present. Also including `-` and `'` so they also get captured within the word. The behavior can be changed/enhanced as per the need though. Just let me know. Enhanced regex to be used will be this,

```
[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+(?: *[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+)*|\d+|[^\w\s]
```

**[Regex Demo supporting accentuated chars](https://regex101.com/r/vJvxyn/2)**

Let me know for any further queries. May be able to respond a bit later as will be on way to home.

Comment: @CarlVerret: Not sure whether OP wants that but can easily extend the character set to contain them as well.

Comment: i'm interrested in how to extend them, i've tried a little without success.  Can you please post ?

Comment: @CarlVerret: Sure, can you please give some sample string containing those accentuated characters and how you want the splitted strings?

Comment: I guess the OP will want support of accentuated characters, considering this is a french address and accents in Towns and Streets names are very common here

Comment: 25 chemin de l'école, Sainte-Mère-Église

Comment: @CarlVerret: I have added support for those accentuated characters as well. Hopefully that should be good and if not, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use split you can use Lookbehind Assertions, most browser now seem to support them, but please check if you want to allow older browsers to work too.

> Edit: Ok, I should have said most browsers look like they will support
>   it.  A quick test and it appears Chrome is the only one atm, and with
>   that I assume Node.js would be fine too.  So this solution might be
>   more useful in the future.  So I'll keep it here, with a big warning
>   on compatibility..

Basically it's 3 splits with two negative lookbehinds, and 1 positive lookahead.

`(?<=\d)` (notice space at end)..  find number but don't capture, and then split on space

`(?<=\w,)` (notice space at end again).. find any word char and comma don't capture and space.

`(?=,)` split on comma and don't capture to keep in output.

```js
const str1 = "21 rue Poliveau, 75005 Paris";
const str2 = "25 chemin de l'école, Sainte-Mère-Églis";

const re_split = /(?<=\d) |(?<=\w,) |(?=,)/;

console.log(str1.split(re_split));
console.log(str2.split(re_split));
```

Comment: this is a nice one!

Comment: Look behind in JavaScript regex isn't widely supported yet and this doesn't work for `21 rue Poliveau,75005 Paris` string as it combines comma and digits together which is why split isn't a good approach here.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi  You not see my big yellow comment?.  Also in Chrome,  `21 rue Poliveau,75005 Paris` is giving me `["21","rue Poliveau",",","75005","Paris"]` and is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Keith: Ok, good that you've mentioned about negative look behind not working which I didn't read in your answer but my main point is, split won't be effective here. The regex you've written is pretty custom to those strings and won't work in general. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/6GSyho/1) where it clearly shows comma and number will stick together, which is why I don't suggest using split here. And you're doing something wrong if you are seeing that string split properly.

Comment: @Keith: Check splitting your string by removing the space between comma and `Paris` and you will know what I am saying. You will see `,75005` together.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern, you are using a capturing group to match all single characters in this character class `[(\d+),(\b)]`

The characters which are in the capturing group are also returned when splitting, that is why you get so many items in the result.

If you want to use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with your example data there are a few places in your string where you can match to split on:

- After a digit
- Before a comma
- Before an upper cased word at the end of the string

To get those characters and positions you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

```
\s(?=[a-z]|\d|[A-Z][a-z]+$)|(?=,)
```

- `\s` Match whitespace character
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `[a-z]|\d|[A-Z][a-z]+$` Match either a-z, or a digit, or uppercase followed by 1+ lowercase a-z and assert end of the string
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `|` Or
- `(?=,)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is a comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoRO6g/1)

```js
let query = "21 rue Poliveau, 75005 Paris";
var regex = /\s(?=[a-z]|\d|[A-Z][a-z]+$)|(?=,)/g;
var resultat = query.split(regex);
console.log(resultat);
```